# Promoting Babelized ES module code to native Node 14+

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I have lot of javascript written to be run by nodejs, but which we ran through the Babel loader at runtime, so that we could write ES syntax -- in particular using `import` rather than `require`.

We have a layout like:

```
package.json
node_modules/
  ...packages...
top/
  server.js
  fribbity.js
```

`server.js` looks like (I've elided the `babel` import boilerplate) :

```js
import {fribbity} from 'top/fribbity'

const x = fribbity()

console.log(`fribbity = ${x}`)
```

while `fribbity.js` might be

```js
export const fribbity = () => 17
```

I'd like to promote all this code to use native ES modules in Node 14+. I added `"type": "module"` to `package.json`. But now I've run into the module resolution rules. By default, Node now expects my import in `server.js` to be

```
import {fribbity} from './fribbity.js'
```

Are there settings I can apply in `package.json`, or on the `node` command line, that would enable node to resolve the imports as they were originally written? That is, preserving the deep import path style (`import` string begins with no slash or dot, and ends without the ".js" extension)? I've tried several false starts.